# C# playing embedded Windows Media Player in fullscreen

Tags: c#, video, media-player, windows-media-player, axwindowsmediaplayer

I'm working on my eyetracking Windows Forms application. I need to play a video and keep track of eye movements simultaneously. Eyetracking part is done, now I need to open a video. I can open a DialogBox to choose which video to play, but I need to have a fullscreen, in order to make more accurate operations.

In my VideoStream class I have got :

```
public static string videoPath;
    public VideoStream(string path)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        videoPath = path;
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = videoPath;
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
```

with the dockstyle fill, I can make my form maximized, but the video is just playing in a small screen [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItqcP.jpg)

but what I want is actually [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RrLH.jpg)

I tried to use `axWindowsMediaPlayer1.fullScreen = true;` but just expands the borders of the form, not the video itself. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these lines after `initializeComponent()`:

```
FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
WindowsState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
TopMost = true;
```